# I have node JS error for date function what someting wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, express, npm

I have some error about new date(); i use node js and plug-in express npm i build variable date but something wrong compile is error

this is my code .js

```
     var update_time = new Date();
     update_time.formatDate("y/m/d");
```

And i run node this is error

```
/home/kingdark/Repos/api/epg/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:216
          throw ex;
                ^
TypeError: Object Fri Feb 08 2013 14:33:09 GMT+0700 (ICT) has no method 'formatDate'
    at /home/kingdark/Repos/api/epg/src/sync/epg.js:24:22
    at Parser.exports.Parser.Parser.parseString (/home/kingdark/Repos/api/epg/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:199:18)
    at Parser.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at Object.exports.Parser.Parser.reset.saxParser.onclosetag (/home/kingdark/Repos/api/epg/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:183:24)
    at emit (/home/kingdark/Repos/api/epg/node_modules/xml2js/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:589:33)
    at emitNode (/home/kingdark/Repos/api/epg/node_modules/xml2js/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:594:3)
    at closeTag (/home/kingdark/Repos/api/epg/node_modules/xml2js/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:834:5)
    at Object.write (/home/kingdark/Repos/api/epg/node_modules/xml2js/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:1253:29)
    at Parser.exports.Parser.Parser.parseString (/home/kingdark/Repos/api/epg/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:211:31)
    at Parser.__bind [as parseString] (/home/kingdark/Repos/api/epg/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:6:61)
    at /home/kingdark/Repos/api/epg/src/sync/epg.js:16:15
```

How to fix that maybe my syntax is wrong,sorry for my English skill.

Comment: for "formatDate" what is your require file?

Answer (score 0):

There is no build in method 'formatDate' however you can use something like [node-dateformat](https://github.com/felixge/node-dateformat)

```
var now = new Date();

dateFormat(now, "yyyy/mm/dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

As the first line of the error message shows: `Object ... has no method 'formatDate'`. The Date object in JavaScript does not have format functions like you are trying. Check out the accepted answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/).

Answer (score 0):

**There is no function like `formatdate()` for Date Objects in JavaScripts...**

So just try like below... it will help you....

```
var d = new Date();
var FormattedDate = d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getDate();
alert(FormattedDate);
```